# RUpdate/refresh session variable on CakePhp

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I'm having a problem with Cake Sessions.

In one of my views, I'm showing a value using `$session->read('User.image')`

When the user logs in, the Session is created and everything goes fine. But when the user update the image, the Session variable is not updated.

I'm trying to do the following in the controller in which I'm saving the new image:

```
$this->User->save($data);
$this->Session->delete('User.image');
$this->Session->write('User.image', $data['User']['image']);
```

If I print `$this->Session->read('User.image')` right in the controller, the updated value is shown correctly. But the image in the header is the same that before until the user login again.

I've already changed the config so cake can save the sessions files in the cake tmp folder so I can write without problems... but it doesn't seems enough.

How can I refresh the Session variable all across the app?? I'm on cake 1.2 branch

Thanks!!